# Angular 2 components/directives in Angular 4

Tags: angular

Can I use Angular 2 components/directives in Angular 4? When I tried to use them I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined`.

Comment: SHow some code.

Comment: *or something similar*. This doesn't help much

Comment: Oh man. I guess it is a angular 1 component.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Angular 2 components and directives in Angular 4 if they don't depend on features that were modified for Angular 4 (breaking changes)

Breaking changes are listed in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Man you are fast!

Comment: And how do I import it? The directive I want use is installed as a npm module having a js file containing the directive: `angular.module('bw.paging', []).directive('paging', function () {...}`. Usually I import modules with `import {Foo} from '...'` but in this case it does not work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.